# Change Pixel Format

Tags: delphi

Can anyone advise how to change a bitmap from 32-bit BGR to 32-bit BGRA using TWICImage?

Comment: Is TWICImage new in Delphi 2010?

Comment: Yes... TWicImage is new in D2010.

Answer (score 0):

Not a specialist, but you may find some info on the interfaces that Delphi exposes [WIC Bitmap Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee690110%28VS.85%29.aspx) , [WIC Format Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee690274%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#methods) and [WIC Bitmap Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee690171%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from the general [WIC API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719800%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)...

Comment: I have been exloring and trying different interfaces but so far this has proved to be more dificult than flipping, sizing, clipping or rotating.